# Intelliji "Problems" toolbar bar not displaying problems

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, ide

My "problems" tab in intellij is not showing a list of problems. It says "No compilation problems found."

I can see that there are problems from the inline color scheme and the scroll bar highlights the problems as well.

What could be causing the issues to not be displayed?

[image]

Comment: This list is for errors reported by the compiler, such as javac. What language/compiler do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am writing in APEX with the IlluminatedCloud plugin

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not supported by this plug-in.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I had it working before. I know it has the ability, I just spun up a new org and am not sure why this one isn't connecting.

Comment: Contact IlluminatedCloud support for help.